# How to replace all values in email template?

Tags: c#, .net, replace

I have an email template

For example this

> Hello @FirstName@ @LastName@

I have an object that comes from a parameter with properties

I need to iterate all object properties and replace all words that matched the property name quoted with "" with property value.

So, for example, I have an object with FirstName and LastName, I need to iterate this object property and change @FirstName@ and @LastName@ in email.

I try to write this method

```
private string ReplaceTemplateValues(object input, string emailTemplate)
{
    foreach(var property in input.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var replacedTemplate = emailTemplate.Replace($"@{property.Name}@", property);
    }
}
```

But how I can get property value in `var replacedTemplate = emailTemplate.Replace($"@{property.Name}@", property);`

and return whole replaced string?

Comment: Personally, I'm using [Razor Engine Core](https://github.com/adoconnection/RazorEngineCore) for these kind of things (there is also a non-Core version, IIRC). Using it successfully since years.

Comment: I don't want to use Razor, I need just replace and return replaced string @UweKeim

Comment: To get value: `property.GetValue(input)`

Comment: It will return string? I guess no @KlausGütter

Comment: It will return whatever the data type of the property is - you might call `.ToString()` on the returned value.

Comment: Okay, thanks @KlausGütter

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to rurn it the other way round: look for `@...@` in the template string and replace it by the values from the input object. This will also behave nice if you happen to have `@X@` in the template but there is no property X.

To extract the property names from the template, you can use regular expressions:

```
private string ReplaceTemplateValues(object input, string emailTemplate)
{
    return Regex.Replace(emailTemplate, @"@(?<prop>\w+)@", m =>
    {
        var property = input.GetType().GetProperty(m.Groups["prop"].Value);
        if (property != null)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(input);
            if (value != null)
                return value.ToString();
        }
        return "";
    });
}
```

Explanation of the Regex (see also [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups))

- `@` will match a literal "@"
- `(?<prop>\w+)` will match at least one (that's the `+`, see [quantifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#match-one-or-more-times-)) "word character" (that's the `\w`, see [character classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w) - I assume that your property names are represented as such) and put the result in a group named "prop" (see [named subexpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-matched-subexpressions))
- `@` will match another literal "@"

`m.Groups["prop"].Value` will get you the matched group, i.e. the property name.

Comment: As I understood if the property is not found it will return an empty value?

And not understood this construction `(m.Groups["prop"].Value)`, how it works?

Comment: Yes. Also added some explanation about the regex.

Comment: Seems `var property` is always null, when I send this object `{"FirstName" : "Eugene" , "LastName": "Sukhomlyn"}`

Comment: This is a JSON representation, how does your C# class look like?